# Flattening out a TreeView in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have some hierarchical that I'd like to display in a TreeView, but formatted to look like a ListBox.

The data I have looks like this (with the possibility of any number of sub levels):

```
Item 1
  Child 1
  Child 2
Item 2
  Child 3
  Child 4
```

I'd like the data to be displayed like this (and wrap when need):

```
Item 1 Child 1 Child 2 Item 2 Child 3 Child 4
```

I'd like to use the TreeView so I can maintain the relationship between the parent and child items which is why I don't want to use a ListBox.
Thanks!

Comment: For lack of time to write up a proper answer, consider using a list box with grouping, the grouping can be found in the `CollectionViewSource` class

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the issue you have is that you don't have a clear separation between your data structure and your view.  If you have a tree which is not WPF it should be easy to map a tree view onto it.  If you have a tree, you can create an tree node numerator that can be used in a list view.

By doing this, the relationship never changes - just how the data is projected in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to implement a recursive function that will scroll down your tree until it hit the end.  That function would take a referenced list or collection as parameter and the current node.

here is the pseudo-code for it

`Sub GenerateListFromTree(Node oNode, List oList)`

```
AddItemToList(oNode.Name)

For each Node oChildNode in oNode.Nodes
    GenerateListFromTree(oChildNode,oList)
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: And having built this data structure, what sort of WPF control would you use to display it? Can you make a TreeView or ListBox display items horizontally, or would an ItemsContainer be better?

Comment: I am by no mean an expert on treeview, but like any WPF control, it is possible to customize it so that it will display it horizontally. In this situation though, I might use a listbox or listview. If each leaf item has a link to its parent, I don't think it really matters.